# Python convert int to string preserving zeros

Tags: python, string, int, zero

i'd like to convert a decimal to a string, where zeros at the end are preserved.
Using str method erases the last zeros.

Example:

```
number=0.20
```

Goal: `"0.20"`

e.g. using: `str(number)="0.2"` doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

If you want 2 decimal places use:

```
number = 0.20
str_number = '%.2f' % number
```

Number before `f` indicates the desired number of places.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using string formatting.

```
"{0:.2f}".format(number)
```

Will return `0.20`.

Doing your chosen method won't work because upon declaring `number = 0.20` it omits the last zero right away. If you put that into your idle:

```
number = 0.20
number
0.2
```

So declaring `number` as `str(number)` is doing `str(0.2)`.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `%` operator with an appropriate format string:

```
'%1.2f' % number
=> '0.20'
```